# How to specify prior distribution

Tags: analysis, bayesian, winbugs

I am conducting a bayesian analysis in winbugs. Here is my model:

```
 y[i] ~ dnorm( mu[i], tau )
 b[i] ~ dnorm(0.0, alpha)    

 mu_i = 1- (beta1*x1 + beta2*x2 + ... + beta20*x20) + b[i]
```

where b[i] is the i-th random effect. I am wondering how I can specify prior distributions for   tau, alpha and the betas. What points are considered? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you use `dgamma` for prior distribution of precision parameter:

```
tau ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
alpha ~ dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
```

For regression coefficients, I would use something like flat normal:

```
beta ~ dnorm(0, 1/(100000^2))
```

[More info on regression coefficients here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40388/5509).